# Tag pages for nonexistent tags

Tags: bug, tags

A link like [this-tag-does-not-exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/this-tag-does-not-exist) leads to a perfectly valid tag page. Obviously this does not break anything on the site, so there is no big problem here, but still - is this an expected behavior or a bug? If it is intentional - what is the purpose of not telling the user that the tag does not exist?

Comment: This is by design. I don't know the full reasoning behind it but it's probably better than showing a 404 page.

Comment: @ChrisF, not showing 404 is fine. But why not tell the user something "This tag does not exist. Would you like to create it?". Actually there is a potential problem with this. Say user is constructing a question query via URL, and writes `/questions/tagged/hmtl+css`. Because of the typo (`hmtl` instead of `html`) the query won't return anything, and won't explain why

Comment: Actually the more I think of it the more sensible it would be to have some sort of message there.

Comment: @Andrei The suggestion in your comment to have a 'Would you like to create it' is not good idea, I foresee a lot of useless tags being created in that case. Currently new tags can only be created by adding one to an existing question. Tags that have no questions associated with it are *soft-deleted*.

Comment: @rene, all right, lets not give an opportunity to create a new tag there. The main point is to indicate that the tag does not exist instead of just showing an empty tag page