# Prevent adding non-existent 'favourite tags'

Tags: bug, tag-watching

I noticed that the ordering of my tags had changed and PHP (my preferred tag) had been moved to the end ([plugging](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/314640/favourite-tags-order)).

I then noticed that I could add non-existent tags and was hoping if this could be validated as it doesn't make much sense to be able to add non-existent tags.

[image]

Comment: You mean you've never heard of the technology called [tag:idefinitelydontexist] ?

Comment: @George Something like that... Maybe SO is powered by it? :O

Comment: Adding non-existant tags helps those of us who don't want the question feed highlighted in garish pastel orange with our "most active" tags. Which I believe is the default behaviour when you haven't added any favourite tags.

Comment: There's no such thing as a tag that doesn't exist. It's just a Javascript library waiting to be created.

Comment: @NisargShah We should merge [tag:idontexist] and [tag:idontexist.js]

Comment: I could see someone potentially wanting this, since maybe they are interested in a technology for which a tag doesn't yet exist. But even if that was the case and we'd want to let them do that, there should at least be a warning if you tried to add a non-existent tag.

Comment: Related: [Tag pages for nonexistent tags](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261516/tag-pages-for-nonexistent-tags)

Comment: I bet `idefinitelydontexist` is where Jon Skeet made his million. LOL

Comment: @theGtknerd Actually Jon Skeet made his million from a bounty on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5487929/4284627).

Comment: Note that you can use [wildcards](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8211/what-are-the-hidden-features-of-stack-exchange/92308#92308) in your favorite / ignored tag lists. If this feature was implemented, there should still be some way to add those. Probably the easiest way would be to keep the interface mostly the same, but just add a warning / confirmation dialog if the tag being added does not exist and contains no wildcards.